# Svn to Git migration - command returned error: 128

Tags: git, git-svn

I am trying to migrate a couple of exising svn repositories to a GIT repositories using git svn utlity.

Note : I am on Windows 11 Enterprise Edition and my svn repository is on a windows machine as well.

While running the svn git clone command : git svn clone --stdlayout --authors-file=authors.txt  https://path/to/repository . , I am getting the below error :

```
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/GitLocalRepo/XXX/.git\svn\refs\remotes\origin\https;C:\Program Files\Git\index.lock': Invalid argument
        (in cleanup) update-index -z --index-info: command returned error: 128
W: +empty_dir: branches/https:/XXX/svn/CalendarMS/sprint2/src/main/resources/static
W: +empty_dir: branches/https:/XXX/svn/CalendarMS/sprint2/src/main/resources/templates
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/GitLocalRepo/TimeOffMS/.git\svn\refs\remotes\origin\https;C:\Program Files\Git\index.lock': Invalid argument
write-tree: command returned error: 128
```

NB : I already cloned two other repos(rather simple ones) from the same server successfully.

I do not understand what this error means and how to solve it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.